# ¿Como puedo Enviar datos mediante ajax de un dominio a otro?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, dominio

Quiero enviar ciertos datos por ajax de un dominio a otro

```
 $.ajax({
                    url:'urldominio2/miarchivo.php',
                    type:'post',
                    contentType:false,
                    data:data,
                    processData:false,
                    cache:false
                  });
```

Al otro lado en mi dominio 2 recibo la informacion mediante post pero obtengo los siguientes errores,

[image: Error]

¿alguien sabe de que manera puedo solucionarlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo visto es un error de cors, si el servidor es en php y tenes acceso, te recomiendo que agregues este codigo en la cabecera del mismo.

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
header("Allow: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
```

Comment: Gracias! funciono perfecto, soluciono el error!

Comment: Me alegro mucho! @JhonPiraquive

Comment: Ten en cuenta que permitir acceso entre dominios se considera un grave riesgo de seguridad.
Te recomendaría que analices cómo prevenir ataques cross-domain.